# Polynomial Multiplication Degree Math Incorrect with Linked Lists

Tags: java, loops, math, linked-list, logic

My multiply logic is incorrect somewhere here. It seems that I am not accounting for when I have to add terms of the same degree I get from the result of multiplying the two polynomials.

```
public Polynomial multiply(Polynomial p) {
    if (p.poly == null || this.poly == null) {
        Polynomial zero = new Polynomial();
        zero.poly = new Node (0, 0, null);
        return zero;
    } else {

        Polynomial retPol = new Polynomial();
        retPol.poly = new Node(0, 0, null);

        Node front = retPol.poly;
        Node entered = p.poly;
        Node thisPol = this.poly;

        int high = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int low = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        while (entered != null) {
            thisPol = this.poly; 

            while (thisPol != null) {
                if (thisPol.term.degree + entered.term.degree > high)
                    high = thisPol.term.degree + entered.term.degree;
                if (thisPol.term.degree + entered.term.degree < low)
                    low = thisPol.term.degree + entered.term.degree;

                thisPol = thisPol.next;
            }

            entered = entered.next;
        }

        entered = p.poly;

        Node create = front;
        for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) { 
            create.term.degree = i;
            create.term.coeff = 0;

            create.next = new Node (0, 0, null);
            create = create.next;
        }

        entered = p.poly;

        while (entered != null) {
            thisPol = this.poly; 

            while (thisPol != null) {
                int degree = entered.term.degree + thisPol.term.degree;
                create = front;

                while (create != null) {
                    if (create.term.degree == degree) {
                        create.term.coeff = entered.term.coeff * thisPol.term.coeff;
                    }

                    create = create.next;
                }

                thisPol = thisPol.next;
            }

            entered = entered.next;
        }

        create = front;

        while (create != null) {
            if (create.term.degree == high) {
                create.next = null;
                create = create.next;
            }
            else
                create = create.next;
        }

        retPol.poly = front;

        return retPol;
    }
}
```

The answer I should be getting is:

`32.0x^9 + 16.0x^8 + -16.0x^7 + -20.0x^6 + 52.0x^5 + 38.0x^4 + -6.0x^3 + -6.0x^2 + 9.0x + 27.0`

but I'm actually getting:

`32.0x^9 + 16.0x^8 + -16.0x^7 + -8.0x^6 + 16.0x^5 + 24.0x^4 + 12.0x^3 + -6.0x^2 + -9.0x + 27.0`

It seems that the 3rd to 6th degree logic is incorrect. It's a logical error, I'm aware. I'm just not sure how to come to solution. I also know that who terms should be added for those incorrect degrees but instead it just looks like it's bypassing that and only displaying one.

Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should summarize for all pairs instead of picking last (or random) pair in here:

```
                if (create.term.degree == degree) {
                    create.term.coeff += entered.term.coeff * thisPol.term.coeff;
                }
```

[UPDATE] Your code with my correction works perfectly for me:

```
public class PolynomialTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 4x^5 - 2x^3 + 2x + 3
        Polynomial p1 = new Polynomial(new Node(4.0, 5, new Node(-2.0, 3, new Node(2.0, 1, new Node(3.0, 0, null)))));
        // 8x^4 + 4x^3 - 3x + 9
        Polynomial p2 = new Polynomial(new Node(8.0, 4, new Node(4.0, 3, new Node(-3.0, 1, new Node(9.0, 0, null)))));
        Polynomial p3 = p1.multiply(p2);
        System.out.println(p3.toString());
    }
}

class Term {
    int degree;
    double coeff;
}

class Node {
    Term term;
    Node next;
    public Node(double coeff, int degree, Node next) {
        this.term = new Term();
        this.term.degree = degree;
        this.term.coeff = coeff;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

class Polynomial {
    private Node poly;

    public Polynomial() {}

    public Polynomial(Node poly) {
        this.poly = poly;
    }

    public Polynomial multiply(Polynomial p) {
        if (p.poly == null || this.poly == null) {
            Polynomial zero = new Polynomial();
            zero.poly = new Node (0, 0, null);
            return zero;
        } else {

            Polynomial retPol = new Polynomial();
            retPol.poly = new Node(0, 0, null);

            Node front = retPol.poly;
            Node entered = p.poly;
            Node thisPol = this.poly;

            int high = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            int low = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

            while (entered != null) {
                thisPol = this.poly; 

                while (thisPol != null) {
                    if (thisPol.term.degree + entered.term.degree > high)
                        high = thisPol.term.degree + entered.term.degree;
                    if (thisPol.term.degree + entered.term.degree < low)
                        low = thisPol.term.degree + entered.term.degree;

                    thisPol = thisPol.next;
                }

                entered = entered.next;
            }

            entered = p.poly;

            Node create = front;
            for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) { 
                create.term.degree = i;
                create.term.coeff = 0;

                create.next = new Node (0, 0, null);
                create = create.next;
            }

            entered = p.poly;

            while (entered != null) {
                thisPol = this.poly; 

                while (thisPol != null) {
                    int degree = entered.term.degree + thisPol.term.degree;
                    create = front;

                    while (create != null) {
                        if (create.term.degree == degree) {
                            create.term.coeff += entered.term.coeff * thisPol.term.coeff;
                        }

                        create = create.next;
                    }

                    thisPol = thisPol.next;
                }

                entered = entered.next;
            }

            create = front;

            while (create != null) {
                if (create.term.degree == high) {
                    create.next = null;
                    create = create.next;
                }
                else
                    create = create.next;
            }

            retPol.poly = front;

            return retPol;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Node n = poly;
        while (n != null) {
            if (sb.length() > 0)
                sb.append(" + ");
            sb.append(n.term.coeff);
            if (n.term.degree > 0)
                sb.append("x");
            if (n.term.degree > 1)
                sb.append("^").append(n.term.degree);
            n = n.next;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

This code prints exactly what you expected:

```
27.0 + 9.0x + -6.0x^2 + -6.0x^3 + 38.0x^4 + 52.0x^5 + -20.0x^6 + -16.0x^7 + 16.0x^8 + 32.0x^9
```

Comment: What do you mean by no luck? Wrong numbers?

Comment: What polynomials are you trying to multiply? You only showed expected resulting polynomial without inputs.

Comment: Whoops sorry. `[4x^5 - 2x^3 + 2x + 3]*[8x^4 + 4x^3 - 3x + 9]`

Comment: @qqxx, I just checked, all seems to work perfectly. See my update for complete example.